# Angular 7 - Make Last Item in Array A Link Using ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, angular8

I have a list of menu items and I want to make the last item in the array a link.

Right now the menu items are built from a component, but I'm unsure of how to make the last item in the array a link.

**ActionMenuItem.component.html**

```
  <div *ngIf="expanded">
  <actionmenuitem *ngFor="let child of line.children" [line]="child" (inWorkspace)="toWorkspace($event)"></actionmenuitem>
```

**ActionMenuItem.Component.ts**

```
  onSelect(){
// If it has children, expand them && flip carat.
if(this.line.children.length > 0){

  this.expanded = !this.expanded;

  if(this.iconName == "expand_more"){
    this.iconName = "expand_less"
  } else {
    this.iconName = "expand_more"
  }

} else {
  this.inWorkspace.emit(this.line);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say make it a link?

Comment: I’m trying to use the router to link to another view in the application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qtcrvi?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let child of line.children;let i=index">

    <actionmenuitem *ngIf="i != (line.children.length-1)" [line]="child" (inWorkspace)="toWorkspace($event)">
    </actionmenuitem>

    <a [routerLink]="[child]" *ngIf="i == (line.children.length-1)">{{child}}</a>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Ok this works, but in my list the array keeps repeating.. any way to fix this?

Comment: Show your list.

Answer (score 5):

Angular exposes the following variables which you can make use of:

- first
- last
- even
- index
- odd

So to make the the last item a link you can do this

```
<div *ngFor="let child of line.children; let last = islast">
   <actionmenuitem *ngIf="islast" [line]="child" 
(inWorkspace)="toWorkspace($event)">
    </actionmenuitem>
</div>
```

Comment: this makes sense but how would i add the link in this?

Comment: @kjamp you can simply add the link inside your *ngFor.
    <a *ngIf="isLast">link here</a>

Comment: i'm not getting this to work right.. it isn't showing my list properly

Comment: It should work with `...; let islast = last`.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to fix last flag assignment:

- let isLast = last
  or
- last as isLast